# Apply function, to save mailitems from inbox, to save mailitems from sub-folders

Tags: vba, outlook

The following Outlook VBA code saves all emails in a specified default folder in Outlook (inbox, sent items, etc.) as .msg files in a directory on the user's desktop.

It does not function correctly for sub-folders.

For example, if the user has already created a sub-folder within the inbox folder or any other default folders in Outlook, the code will not run correctly.

How could I revise the code so that it can function for any Outlook folder?

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim StrSavePath     As String

Sub SaveAllEmails_ProcessAllSubFolders()
      
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim n               As Long
    Dim StrSubject      As String
    Dim StrName         As String
    Dim strFile         As String
    Dim StrReceived     As String
    Dim StrFolder       As String
    Dim StrSaveFolder   As String
    Dim strFolderpath   As String
    Dim iNameSpace      As NameSpace
    Dim myOlApp         As Outlook.Application
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
    Dim mItem           As MailItem
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ChosenFolder    As Object
    Dim Folders         As New Collection
    Dim EntryID         As New Collection
    Dim StoreID         As New Collection
      
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
    Set iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ChosenFolder = iNameSpace.PickFolder
    If ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
GoTo ExitSub:
    End If
      
    BrowseForFolder StrSavePath
         
    Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)
      
    For i = 1 To Folders.Count
        StrFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
        n = InStr(3, StrFolder, "\") + 1
        StrFolder = Mid(StrFolder, n, 256)
        strFolderpath = StrSavePath & "\" & StrFolder & "\"
        StrSaveFolder = Left(strFolderpath, Len(strFolderpath) - 1) & "\"
        If Not FSO.FolderExists(strFolderpath) Then
            FSO.CreateFolder (strFolderpath)
        End If
          
        Set SubFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
        On Error Resume Next
        For j = 1 To SubFolder.Items.Count
            Set mItem = SubFolder.Items(j)
            StrReceived = Format(mItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYY-MM-DD_hh.mm")
            StrSubject = mItem.Subject
            StrName = StripIllegalChar(StrSubject)
            strFile = StrSaveFolder & StrReceived & "_" & StrName & ".msg"
            strFile = Left(strFile, 256)
            mItem.SaveAs strFile, 3
        Next j
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
      
ExitSub:
      
End Sub

  
Function StripIllegalChar(StrInput)
    Dim RegX            As Object
      
    Set RegX = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      
    RegX.Pattern = "[\" & Chr(34) & "\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\=\+\|\[\]\{\}\`\'\;\:\<\>\?\/\,]"
    RegX.IgnoreCase = True
    RegX.Global = True
      
    StripIllegalChar = RegX.Replace(StrInput, "")
      
ExitFunction:
    Set RegX = Nothing
      
End Function
  

Sub GetFolder(Folders As Collection, EntryID As Collection, StoreID As Collection, Fld As MAPIFolder)
    Dim SubFolder       As MAPIFolder
      
    Folders.Add Fld.FolderPath
    EntryID.Add Fld.EntryID
    StoreID.Add Fld.StoreID
    For Each SubFolder In Fld.Folders
        GetFolder Folders, EntryID, StoreID, SubFolder
    Next SubFolder
      
ExitSub:
    Set SubFolder = Nothing
      
End Sub
  
  
Function BrowseForFolder(StrSavePath As String, Optional OpenAt As String) As String
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim objFolder '  As Folder

    Dim enviro
    enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, enviro & "\Desktop\")
    StrSavePath = objFolder.self.Path

    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0
      
ExitFunction:
    Set objShell = Nothing
      
End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached? Do you get any errors in the code?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and post the exact error you get.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem can be try to remove the `On Error` statements from the code. Otherwise, the code will continue execution without stopping at the point where the error takes place.

Also in Outlook VBA you may use the `Application` property, so instead of the following code:

```
Set myOlApp = Outlook.Application
Set iNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

You could simply write the following:

```
Set iNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
```

And in the loop you could use the `iNamespace` object instead of calling the `Session` property:

```
Set SubFolder = myOlApp.Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
```

Use the `Namespace` object retrieved earlier:

```
Set SubFolder = iNamespace.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `On Error Resume Next` will be incorrectly used. Not incorrect here just ugly.
You could replace it with a test to ensure the item is a mailitem. Then there would be no errors returning mailitem properties from non-mailitems to be bypassed.

If there is a misunderstanding about the user input for `BrowseForFolder`, hard coding addresses user error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim StrSavePath     As String

Sub SaveAllEmails_ProcessAllSubFolders()
      
    Dim i               As Long
    Dim j               As Long
    Dim n               As Long
    
    Dim StrSubject      As String
    Dim StrName         As String
    Dim strFile         As String
    Dim StrReceived     As String
    Dim StrFolder       As String
    Dim StrSaveFolder   As String
    Dim strFolderpath   As String
    
    Dim SubFolder       As Folder
    Dim mItem           As MailItem
    Dim subFolItems     As Items
    
    Dim FSO             As Object
    Dim ChosenFolder    As Object
    
    Dim Folders         As New Collection
    Dim EntryID         As New Collection
    Dim StoreID         As New Collection
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set ChosenFolder = Session.PickFolder
    
    If Not ChosenFolder Is Nothing Then
        
        ' If code previously used, choose the same folder as on first run
        'BrowseForFolder StrSavePath
        
        ' You could hard code the starting folder instead
        Dim enviro As String
        enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
        StrSavePath = enviro & "\Desktop"
        
        Call GetFolder(Folders, EntryID, StoreID, ChosenFolder)
          
        For i = 1 To Folders.count
            
            StrFolder = StripIllegalChar(Folders(i))
            n = InStr(3, StrFolder, "\") + 1
            StrFolder = Mid(StrFolder, n, 256)
            Debug.Print StrFolder
            
            strFolderpath = StrSavePath & "\" & StrFolder & "\"
            Debug.Print " strFolderpath: " & strFolderpath
            
            StrSaveFolder = Left(strFolderpath, Len(strFolderpath) - 1) & "\"
            Debug.Print StrSaveFolder
            
            If Not FSO.folderExists(strFolderpath) Then
                FSO.createFolder (strFolderpath)
            End If
            
            Set SubFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(EntryID(i), StoreID(i))
            
            Set subFolItems = SubFolder.Items
            
            For j = 1 To subFolItems.count
            
                If subFolItems(j).Class = olMail Then
                
                    Set mItem = subFolItems(j)
                                        
                    StrReceived = Format(mItem.ReceivedTime, "YYYY-MM-DD_hh.mm")
                    StrSubject = mItem.subject
                    StrName = StripIllegalChar(StrSubject)
                    
                    strFile = StrSaveFolder & StrReceived & "_" & StrName & ".msg"
                    strFile = Left(strFile, 256)
                    mItem.SaveAs strFile, 3
                    
                    Set mItem = Nothing

                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    
End Sub
```